# Ethereum 2.0: supermajority, stake distribution among validators

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain

I am studying how the Ethereum 2.0 version works. I have read the official documentation and in particular [this](https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain/).
According to the information I found [here](https://ethresear.ch/t/simplified-active-validator-cap-and-rotation-proposal/9022), the maximum number of validators allowed is MAX_VALIDATOR_COUNT 2 ** 19 (= 524,288) ~16.7M ETH (in the past the value was 2 ** 22).

I cannot determine what the actual number of network validators selected for block validation is. I have read that a committee has at least 128 validators and therefore a total of shards * validators=64 * 128=8192 randomly selected validators. The beacon chain is validated by at least 128 validators, can this value be considered as the actual number of validators in use for each slot?

The FFG consensus algorithm needs a supermajority of 2/3 to work. Is it possible to know the distribution of the 32 ETH coins needed for staking among the validators? That is, how many validators own 33%, 51% and 67% of the coins? I found some partial information on [this website](https://ethscan.org/charts/deposits_distribution).

Thank you

Comment: Can you precise your question? If you know all the validators and their stake, why are you looking for the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The best source of information is either lookking directly at the code specifications [here](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md) or a more digest version (not yet complete) [here](https://eth2book.info/).

There you can see that: `MAX_COMMITTEES_PER_SLOT` is 64 and `MAX_VALIDATORS_PER_COMMITTEE` is 2,048. Given the fact that there is 32 slots per epoch this gives a total of 4,194,304 validators maximum. We are currently at [400k validators](https://beaconcha.in/) so we need ten times the amount already staked to reach this bound. And currently, approximatively [10%](https://etherscan.io/accounts) of the total ETH supply is already staked. The bound would then be reached if every ETH is staked, *coïncidence*?